# Internal Server Error. Where to find the log files?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I know one location is **/etc/httpd/logs/** . There are number of files. So I deleted all and tried to run the error page and got the following

```
./  ../  archive/  fpcgisock=  suexec_log  suphp_log
```

Not sure what file it is actually. I was hoping for error_log file but it's not there.

I have centos 6.

Comment: Each domain/virtual host can have its own log, you should have a look through your httpd.conf, and other files under /conf.d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting the files you need to restart the httpd service as the log files are being held open (via an fd) and being written to by the httpd daemon.

```
service httpd restart
```

Generally you'll find logs in /var/log/httpd and usually they are named for their function

```
access_log
error_log
```

etc. Now would be a good time to have a look at the apache documentation, it's really rather good.